# Power won't turn on on my Sony Linear PCM recorder Model PCM-D50

Tags: power, troubleshooting, sony-pcm-d50

I purchased the Sony PCM D50 recorder in 2009 and first used it on a trip through Blues country in Louisiana with a reporter. I stored it away after a year. I pulled it out of my electronics box this week (to start recording my family's history) and have found that the power does not come on. I tried all actions on the trouble shooting list: I changed the AA batteries, turned the hold button to "off" and while I do not have the original DC Input, I have a substitute. Nothing works. I remember this was an expensive purchase and the sound quality was excellent. It's a discontinued model that I want to save. Any suggestions? Much appreciated.

Comment: speak to a Sony distributor or a local repair shop.

Comment: Thank you Mark. That was my next step. Just wanted to check if I was missing something obvious as I'm in a DIY mode these days.